# Observable.next doesn't work when called from ngOnInit

Tags: angular, rxjs

1.

I'm trying to do something like `ngrx/redux` from scratch and faced problem.

Basically I want to send an event from ngOnInit and state should change.
Also should print that event was processed.

I don't know if problem is in AppComponent - subscription is inside template:

```
<div *ngIf="(state$ | async) as state">
  This is state {{state | json}}
</div>
```

or something with wrong type for action$ (currently Subject).

2.
Why this works when invoked by `router.navigate(...)`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9fbvu

Answer (score 1):

Angular starts checking template after `ngOnInit` hook was fired.

This means that your `state$` observable doesn't have any subscribers at the time of execution `ngOnInit`.

Another key point here is that you're using `Subject` for actions that doesn't hold previous values. Once you replace it with `BehaviorSubject` it should start working

```
actions$: Subject<Action> = new Subject<Action>();
                                 ||
                                 \/
actions$: Subject<Action> = new BehaviorSubject<Action>(null);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7tj28c?file=src/app/facade.ts)**